# How to respect encapsulation principles in c++ without making the code unefficient?

Tags: c++, oop, pass-by-reference, encapsulation

i am a noobie in c++ programming and i'm developing a project in c++.
I am new to the all the OOP principles like encapsulation and inheritance, and due to this i have a doubt on how to properly design the code in particular structures.
Suppose for example i have to define a structure like that:

```
class c1;
class c2;

class MyCl{
public:
  MyCl();
  // many access methods...
  //...
  //...
private:
  std::string _title;
  int _version;
  std::vector<c1> _vec;
  // other private members
}

class c1{
public:
  c1();
  // many access methods
private:
  std::vector<c2> _vec;
  // other private members
}

class c2{
public:
  c2();
  //many access methods
private:
  std::vector<std::string> _vec_str;
  // other private members
}
```

Now suppose we have an object of MyCl and we want to modify a single string amongst all in the vector **_vec_str**, placed in the least exposed part of the structure(c2).
So in that case what is the best option to modify that string respecting the encapsulation principle? Returning const& seems unefficient, as in order to modify a single string we have to copy all the structure two times (one for the getters, and one for the setters) and for each subclass. On the other hand, returning & or pointers is more efficient as it allows a direct access to all the structure, but it doesn't respect encapsulation principles.

Comment: Without some idea of what the classes actually do, it's a bit meaningless to talk about how to effectively encapsulate them and what their exposed interface should be.

Comment: You want the "wrong" thing - `MyCl` shouldn't even know that there is a vector of strings somewhere deep within that could be modified. `c1` and `c2` should expose mutating functions that don't leak implementation details; `MyCl` should ask a `c1` to do something, and that in turn should ask a `c2` to do something. (And if you have "many" accessors, you're most likely far along the wrong track.)

Comment: Please modify the question and explain what is the purpose of the particular class, preferably just one to avoid long meaningless code sample. Currently I can only say "it depends". E.g.: simple entity like "Point" might be better as a `struct Point{ T x, T y };` while a complex geometric figure might be better as a `class Rectangle` with accessors and methods to calculate different parameters (e.g. area).